# F2 focus in Eclipse for deprecated members

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, the F2/focus or a hover on a member gives you a popup with the javadocs. However, if the member is deprecated, you only get a message like 'The field blahblah is deprecated'.

Does anyone know if this is a known bug/feature? If yes, is there a handy shortcut to get a javadoc popup for deprecated members?

Typically the alternate use of the a deprecated member is in the @deprecated javadoc tag. Hence the interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo do observe this behavior even in latest 3.5 releases.

One solution is to click on the function and to have the javadoc view opened.
Even if the method is deprecated, the javadoc will be displayed in the javadoc view.

[alt text http://help.eclipse.org/help32/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/images/JavadocView.png](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/images/JavadocView.png)

---

Another solution:

`Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors >`**`Annotations`**:

**Click on warnings, un-select "Text as"**.

The underline disappear, and you can hover and see the javadoc in the F2/focus view.